# r dplyr filter with a dynamic variable name

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to select only the rows without NAs:

```
library(dplyr)
x = data.frame(a = c(NA, 2, 3, 4))
var_a <- "a"
# This works:
x %>% filter(!is.na(a))
# That works too:
var_a <- quo(a)
x %>% filter(!is.na(!!var_a))
# But this doesn't work:
var_a <- "a"
x %>% filter(!is.na(!!var_a))
```

What should I change in the last line for it to work? Because I have to work with var_a <- "a".
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a string, so we can convert to symbol with `sym` and then use `!!`

```
x %>% 
   filter(!is.na(!!rlang::sym(var_a)))
#  a
#1 2
#2 3
#3 4
```

---

Or another option is to specify the object in `filter_at` and then do the filtering

```
x %>% 
   filter_at(var_a, all_vars(!is.na(.)))
#  a
#1 2
#2 3
#3 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Man, it's a bit of a pain with dplyr.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than referencing by name of column, just give it the entire column to filter by.

```
x = data.frame(a = c(NA, 2, 3, 4))
var_a <- "a"
x %>% filter(!is.na(!!x[,var_a]))
```

Noticed I've just changed `var_a` to `x[,var_a]`.

Comment: Notice this couldn't go in the middle of a dplyr stack though